# Uptime tracker for linux

Tags: linux, open-source, time-management

I use [PC On/Off Time](https://www.neuber.com/free/pctime/) for Windows. It reads the system's boot/shutdown events from the system log and displays them in a nice GUI:

[image: PC On/Off Time GUI]

<sub>As a side note, I wrote a [PowerShell script (Windows only)](https://github.com/ThomasR/goodTimes) that does the same thing, but without GUI.</sub>

Is there a similar tool for Linux? It should

- Show daily uptime intervals and daily total
- Consider suspend/wake up as well as boot/shutdown
- Work nicely with sessions that span over midnight
- A GUI would be nice to have, but textual output is ok
- Open Source

I don't need the network feature. Local machine only.

Comment: Well, you could use [graylog](https://www.graylog.org/) or [kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) with a good set of configurations will do much more than that

Comment: Why would a Linux machine ever be down, or even reboot? Just draw a stright line ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I may be a weird one, but the only Linux machines that I turn on/off on a "as I'm using it" basis would be laptops.  My desktops stay on 24/7 unless we have a power failure, and my servers I've rebooted occasionally but never turned off.

My desktop at the moment - we're in summer storm season here in Florida, and I loose power on occasion or the power blips.  Really need to get a new UPS...

```
user@darkstar ~ $ uptime
 12:59:42 up 4 days, 19:51,  1 user,  load average: 0.11, 0.39, 0.43
user@darkstar ~ $
```